# Why I receive NotSerializableException while attempting to Serialize an Object

Tags: java, serialization, io, objectoutputstream, notserializableexception

I have the following class:

```
public class GameWorld implements Serializable {
    int sumu_dist = 30;
    public List<Tiles> tileGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    public List<Tiles> loadingTiles = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructor etc.
}
```

in another class, I tried to save `GameWorld`, but received not serializable exception:

```
public class game {

    static GameWorld GameWorldObj = new GameWorld();

    String FileName = "WorldData.bin";

void Save(){
    try {
        FileOutputStream FOS = new FileOutputStream(FileName);
        ObjectOutputStream OOS = new ObjectOutputStream(FOS);
        if (gameworld_obj instanceof Serializable){
            OOS.writeObject(GameWorldObj); // java.io.NotSerializableException
        }
        System.out.printf("SAVED: %s \n", OOS);
        OOS.close();
    } catch (IOException exception){
        System.err.println(String.valueOf(exception));
    } 
    
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new game().Save();
}
```

I don't know why it's happen, I search on SO and find some answers told you to implement `Serializable`. I did it, and I'm still receiving `NotSerializableException`.

Why is that to happen? What can I do to fix it?

*Error-message*:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: source.library.level.Tiles
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1197)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1582)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1539)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1448)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1191)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
    at source.library.level.game.Save(game.java:33)
    at source.library.level.game.main(game.java:47)
```

Comment: Show all the fields in the `GameWorld` class. The whole object graph needs to be serializable, if at least one of the fields doesn't implement `Serializable` you'll get an exception.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko It means I need to implement Serializable to enum?

Comment: `Tiles` type is an enum? All enums are serializible, because `java.lang.Enum` their parent implements `Serializable`. Please, past the lines of code from the first image as a text. The second image seems not related to your issue, consider removing it.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko "Tiles" is a class, it use to define tile in game, "GameWorld" is another class use to store Tiles by list "TileGroup". Should I implement Serializable to Tiles?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko it's okay right now, GameWorld is saved success (SAVED: java.io.ObjectOutputStream@5bcab519)

Comment: Sure, `Tiles` has to implement `Serializable`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244001/discussion-between-cflowe-visit-and-alexander-ivanchenko).

Comment: The class `source.library.level.GameWorld$GameMode` is not `Serializable`, just as it says in the exception. And you haven't posted it here, or enough of the `GameWorld` class to see the variable of that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole object graph needs to be serializable, if at least one of the fields doesn't implement `Serializable` interface you'll get an exception while attempting to serialize the instance of this class.

Quote from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html):

> When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not support the Serializable interface. In this case the `NotSerializableException` will be thrown and will identify the class of the non-serializable object.

Primitive types and most of the data-types built-in in the JDK are serializable.

You can run into troubles **only** with these types:

- `Object` doesn't implement `Serializable`, hence `Object` type fields are not allowed in the class that is meant to be serializable.
- `Optional` as well as `OptionalInt`, `OptionalLong` and `OptianalDouble` aren't serializable because optional types were introduced as limited mechanism
  for *return types* and not intended to be used as fields.
- Your custom types used as a field of a serializable class has to be serializable. `Tiles` class has to implement `Serializable` and if there are some custom field types inside the `Tiles`, they must be serializable as well.

If you don't want a particular field to be serialized, you can mark it as `transient`. Transient fields as well as `static` fields are ignored during the serialization process.

So if you would make the fields `tileGroup` and `loadingTiles` to be `transient`, then `Tiles` class will not be required to implement `Serializable` because these attributes will be excluded from the serialized version. And as a consiquence after deserialization they will be initialized to `null`.

In general, serialization is meant to be used for temporary data-storage or transferring the data. To ensure that an object retrieved from memory is compatible with the **.class** file that you have it a good practice to define `static final long serialVersionUID` field, which denotes the current version of the class.

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a
> version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during
> deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized
> object have loaded classes for that object that are compatible with
> respect to serialization. If the receiver has loaded a class for the
> object that has a different serialVersionUID than that of the
> corresponding sender's class, then deserialization will result in an
> InvalidClassException. A serializable class can declare its own
> serialVersionUID explicitly by declaring a field named
> "serialVersionUID" that must be static, final, and of type long:
>
> ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER `static final long serialVersionUID = 42L;`

Also, you should be aware that serialization has some serious draw-backs (*take a look at the link provided above*).

***Sidenote***: class-names are usually *singular nouns* like `Student`, `Employee`, `Tile` because their instances are meant to represent a single object.